# Need help to understand spring config files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying a existing Spring MVC 3 project, while looking into spring and context config files I get confused, please clear it or suggest me If something is wrong.

**Upadte `root-context.xml` file**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages</value>   
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />        
    </bean>


   <bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
        <property name="basenamePrefix" value="detailtheme-" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
        <property name="defaultThemeName" value="en" />
    </bean>


<!-- Helper bean to load all properties files -->
    <bean id="LoadPropertiesFiles" class="org.commons.utilities.LoadPropertiesFileHelper"
        init-method="loadPropertiesFileMethod" lazy-init="false" />
</beans>
```

Here I don't understand what is `lang`? What I understand is it's a veriable name whose value is assigned to `paramName` (`DEFAULT_PARAM_NAME`), but I don't understand how value is assigned to `lang` because I don't find any single location where some value (like en,hi..etc) is set.

The most confusing thing is one more bean with same class is defined in `servlet-context.xml` as :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
...
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Why **two beans** of same class is defined, is this wrong? if not, then what is work of bean defined in `root-context.xml` and `servlet-context.xml`?

Below is `web.xml` for reference:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <!-- Listener to prevent class loader leaks -->
  <listener>
     <listener-class>se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ClassLoaderLeakPreventor</listener-class>
  </listener>  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
      <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/tagTld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/resources/tld/EnumTag.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocaleChangeInterceptor` will intercept web requests to your web app, and look for query param with name `lang` (E.g. http://mywebapp.com/login?lang=en), and try to set app's locale accordingly so that you can do localization of your web app.

As far as two files `root-context.xml` and `servlet-context.xml` is concerned - first file is being used by `<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>` and second file is being used by `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`.

`ContextLoaderListener` can be used to initialize Spring even when you are not necessarily using Spring MVC.  The `DispatcherServlet` is specific to Spring MVC and is needed if you are making use of it.

It may be possible to get rid of `root-context.xml`, but it will require you to review design of  your app as there may be non-SpringMVC components that depend on beans defined `root-context.xml`.

Comment: So is this like `LocaleChangeInterceptor ` will intercept ONLY that request which has query param  with name `lang`? or it will intercept all request and check for query param?

Comment: It will intercept all requests, but will take action only if lang param is present

Comment: What if request is `POST`? and I want to change the locale on it?

Comment: In case of POST, lang can be a parameter in POST, or can be part of URL to which POST is being made.

Comment: Ok,Thanks! To review design of app do you want full root`context.xml file?

Comment: No, I mean if you don't want two -context.xml files, you will have to look at overall design.   Otherwise as Brian pointed out, you may not need bean of LocaleChangeInterceptor in root-context.xml and get rid of it as it is MVC specific

Comment: Oh..ok got it.(I posted full root-context.xml file), so as Brian told it's safe to remove entry from root-context.xml and I can still write `mappings` shown as like here http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor, Right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in servlet-context.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83906/discussion-between-amogh-and-wand-maker).

Comment: The approach we discussed is worked :) Tons of Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this bean definition does not belong to the root context, so you can safely delete the one defined in `root-context.xml` and just leave the one in `servlet-context.xml`.

As for the `paramName` parameter, this is the name of the request parameter that will be used to change the locale - [see reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor).

Comment: What if request is of `POST` type?

Comment: @Amogh why would it be? Also, POST requests can have querystrings.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, because in project i can see some request mapping which are POST method and return to view and actually I got a task that I have to switch the locale to `ar` for that request otherwise default i.e. `en`. I don't know is this possible by `LocaleChangeInterceptor` or not but I will try to...